# How to see Private Information Tab in Odoo 15

Tags: access-rights, odoo-15

I was created an new user by copy action in "Marc Demo" user, and called it "Marc Demo 2", and login to that user, then i go to "My profile" and it show a popup like this:
[image]

But i can't see the "Private Information" tab in this user.

So here's the question: Where is the Access Rights/Groups configured so that an internal user can see the Tab "Private information"?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For making this private information visible, you have to create the user as an employee.

See below image:-

[image]

Click on the "create employee" button as shown in the image for the user you have created.